# Can I create a link to a specific email message in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, emacs, url, org-mode

I use Outlook as my email client at work, but I don't want to use it to manage my tasks and todos. (Instead I use plain text files and Emacs org-mode.) Since many todo items start out as mails in my inbox, I often need to reference these mails.

Is there some clever way to create a link (a URL) that opens a specific email in Outlook when clicked?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do this with a little bit of code in Outlook and a little bit of code in Emacs.

First, if you're using Outlook 2007 you'll need to enable Outlook URLs with a registry addition.  Instructions and the registry file can be found [here](http://www.davidtan.org/outlook-2007-adding-outlook-url-protocol/) courtesy of David Tan.

Next, this macro can be added to Outlook and will get the GUID of the current email message, create a Org-Mode link and deposit it into the clipboard.

```
'Adds a link to the currently selected message to the clipboard
Sub AddLinkToMessageInClipboard()

   Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim doClipboard As New DataObject

   'One and ONLY one message muse be selected
   If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count <> 1 Then
       MsgBox ("Select one and ONLY one message.")
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Set objMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
   doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][MESSAGE: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + objMail.SenderName + ")]]"
   doClipboard.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

As [koushik](https://superuser.com/users/49981/koushik) noted in the comments, the `doClipboard.SetText` part can be expanded to differentiate between different item types:

```
If objMail.Class = olMail Then
    doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][MESSAGE: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + objMail.SenderName + ")]]"
ElseIf objMail.Class = olAppointment Then
    doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][MEETING: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + objMail.Organizer + ")]]"
ElseIf objMail.Class = olTask Then
    doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][TASK: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + objMail.Owner + ")]]"
ElseIf objMail.Class = olContact Then
    doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][CONTACT: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + objMail.FullName + ")]]"
ElseIf objMail.Class = olJournal Then
    doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][JOURNAL: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + objMail.Type + ")]]"
ElseIf objMail.Class = olNote Then
    doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][NOTE: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + " " + ")]]"
Else
    doClipboard.SetText "[[outlook:" + objMail.EntryID + "][ITEM: " + objMail.Subject + " (" + objMail.MessageClass + ")]]"    
End If
```

Almost there, add this little bit of lisp to your emacs lisp directory to enable Outlook links.

```
;;; org-outlook.el - Support for links to Outlook items in Org

(require 'org)

(org-add-link-type "outlook" 'org-outlook-open)

(defun org-outlook-open (id)
   "Open the Outlook item identified by ID.  ID should be an Outlook GUID."
   (w32-shell-execute "open" (concat "outlook:" id)))

(provide 'org-outlook)

;;; org-outlook.el ends here
```

And lastly, update your .emacs file to include the Outlook link code.  Just add this somewhere after org-mode is setup.

```
(require 'org-outlook)
```

Now you can call the macro (I added it to my toolbar in Outlook for quick access) and you can quickly create a link to the email in Emacs.

One gotcha, GUID's change when you move a message between document stores, so if you get the GUID to the message while it's on your Exchange server and then move it to your local PST file the link will change.  Move the message before you get the GUID.

Comment: This is great, thank you! One simplification: I didn't mess with the registry to enable Outlook URLs, instead I just changed the w32-shell-execute call to this: (w32-shell-execute "open" "C:/Programme/Microsoft Office/Office12/OUTLOOK.EXE" (concat "/select " "outlook:" id)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I found out that I somewhat needed to create an empty form to prevent compilation error on undefined DataObject.

Comment: @ChristianBerg: I'm using Outlook 2003, so maybe I can have hyperlinks without bothering with the registry, but your simplification did not work, Outlook was unable to find the URL. And every time I clicked on a link in Emacs, a new outlook-process was started. So I sticked to the great solution by user259...

Comment: This is fantastic ! Thank you for providing this solution. I tried it with outlook 2007 with the registry tweak and it worked like a charm ! I found 1 issue if I ran the macro when I had a meeting invite / appointment selected. The code threw an exception. Since I use it only on the inbox I solved this by Dim objMail as Object instead of MailItem - however this may not be the right solution since the code could still fail if the item selected doesn't have Subject/ SenderName members. The code could probably check if the selected item is of proper type and provide a MsgBox if it is not.

Comment: I "scratched this itch" of mine a bit more as I had to record links to some appointments for working on related items (so I can refer ot info / attachments therein or reply all when I have updates etc). Now this can export mails, calendar items, contacts, notes, journal entries and at least will not fail when invoked on other entries. The modified code is at http://pastebin.com/gNWLVNRk (I can provide a diff if it would help - though I don't know how to make on in VBA). I didn't have to make any other change (emacs-side or regsitry) for this to work on my end. HTH.

Comment: @koushik: Thank you for your great script. Where do you past those links? The syntax [[url][description]] is not recognized by outlook...

Comment: I got a unknown type error for DataObject. After trying out various options such as [add reference to Microsoft  Forms](https://blog.jonschneider.com/2009/12/fix-excel-vba-user-defined-type-not.html) which was not available for adding, and others I came across https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/338020-dataobject-and-cliboard.html and added a dummy userform and it started working

Comment: Any pointers to a macOS equivalent?

Comment: To solve the DataObject type error, the following worked for me. In the macro editor, go to Tools->References. Click browse, select the file `C:\Windows\System32\fm20.dll` and press OK.

Comment: @HugoIdeler: Note that on x64 systems, the location of the dll is C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Comment: @Thomas there appears to be no file 'fm20.dll' at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fm20.dll on my 64 bit system, but it was in the location Hugo specified.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by writing a simple vbscript ([download](https://fs.fnkr.net/e9236fef51fc4257b7bd/dl)):

```
Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set SelectedItem = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.ShellExecute "cmd", "/c echo Outlook:" & SelectedItem.entryID & " | clip", "", "runas", 1
```

It copies a link of the element (Email, Calendar entry, ...) you have currently selected in Outlook to your clipboard:

```
Outlook:176CZREX7A79L9TG1T0AJ6HQ8DEBLTFS60HUQYKT2IXBBZ9ZZVA73MNRYVRWRL4RY0VCPQE1IB5GAWY0D8OSMOB4IFDV5OMG9NX2BBKGFA3IWSD62UCNVK0HD9GA80BIDZSBCZL7INCT
```

You can even use a redirection service so that you get a HTTP link (because `Outlook:` links are probably not detected automatically if you paste is somewhere, but HTTP links are) ([download](https://fs.fnkr.net/c04a416ba13a47539872/dl)), just replace the last line with:

```
Shell.ShellExecute "cmd", "/c echo https://api.fnkr.net/goto/jsclient/raw/?closeAfter=500#Outlook:" & SelectedItem.entryID & " | clip", "", "runas", 1
```

Note that you need to make `Outlook:` links working first.
http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-missing-outlook-protocol/ (scroll down to "Do It For Me")

Tested with Outlook 2010.

Comment: Issue with entryId is it doesn't work after moving the mail

Answer (score 4):

I don't have sufficient reputation credits to put in a comment to the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/100084/777341) above, but I wanted to put a cross-reference in for a revision to the excellent answer provided by @user25995 - which I posted at [(emacs) StackExchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35916/15164).

Based on a comment I received to a question I posted there, I changed the use of (deprecated) `org-add-link-type` to `org-link-set-parameters` and included an `export:` function so that the HTML export backend gave me a properly formatted `<a href="outlook:...">` link type.

Comment: Commentary shouldn't be submitted as an answer because of your inability to submit an actual comment.

Comment: @Ramhound - I took pains to point to the accepted answer, even by providing a link and acknowledging the author. I then offered a small revision that avoids the use of a function that is now deprecated.  I did not intend to breach protocol here - is there a correct way to communicate this if I don't have enough Brownie points to comment on the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

came across Linker applet.going to try it out..you may want to as well
http://www.teamscope.com/otherpro/utilities.asp#linker

Here's the marketing drible..

Linker™ for Windows® creates hyperlinks to items and folders in Outlook, and to files and folders in Windows Explorer. It is a system tray applet places the hyperlink in the Windows clipboard. The hyperlink can then be pasted into any Microsoft Office document, web page, e-mail message, or any document that supports hyperlinks.

Greetings from sunny South Africa!

Comment: Linker works sometimes, other times not so much. Overall feels quite buggy in Win 7 + Outlook 2010

Comment: Using Office Pro Plus 2016 + Win 10 Pro, and it did not work. It breaks when accessing the links that had been copied - so when clicking \\<email address>\Drafts\~test , the unknown app is pick up by win 10 so it breaks.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy an Outlook e-mail to OneNote (comes in as a yellow letter icon), then right click and select 'link to paragraph', and then paste the link into another document that can work with links.

But anyway, Microsoft should have made this whole thing of linking to an e-mail a standard feature. It was such a useful feature of Lotus Notes.

Comment: It's a useful feature.  But, what's the security model?   Do you want a bad guy to send you a link in an email that you might open by accident? GUIDs, sure, not visible outside - unless they leak...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about referencing a specific email but depending on your system you might be able to copy the email to the same location as the todo item. Just drag/drop the mail to a folder or the desktop and it will create a copy of the mail that you can treat as a normal file.

If you would be using .doc or more "advanced" files than .txt you could then link to this Outlook message file.

Comment: I'll go with that solution. Here's my new workflow: Drag the mail to a temporary folder. Create the todo item in org-mode. Add the message file as an attachment to the item: C-c C-a m (the message file is moved to the attachments folder). Later I can open the message from the todo item by pressing C-c C-a o.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to copy the Outlook Item content to the system clipboard and then yank it into an Org-mode note.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PlannerModeContrib#toc10

Answer (score 0):

Not without some kind of custom code.  The Outlook URI's can get you to the containing folder within Outlook, but that's about it.  You would need to come up with a clever filing strategy that aligned with your linking strategy to get more granular.

Comment: Other answers show it's possible, hence the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your requirement is different with mine.

Outook 2013 > Message Tab(your normal view) > 'Actions' Button > View in Browser

Then I get that link from the browser.

Hope that help

Comment: This seemed promising but in `Outlook 2013` for me this creates a `.mht` file in `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook\` and opens that in IE using a 'mhtml:file://..`  url so no go.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/) to manage my tasks and found that with the [Wunderlist add-in for Outlook](https://support.wunderlist.com/customer/portal/articles/2279134-wunderlist-add-in-for-outlook) I can create new tasks directly from an email message and Wunderlist automatically creates a link in the task notes to the original message. A few things to keep in mind:

1. I always move the message to a folder first because (last time I 
   checked) the URL breaks if you later move the message to another folder.
2. Even though there is an add-in for Outlook desktop, it doesn't seem to include the link, so I use Outlook on the Web when I
   want to create a task.
3. I have only tried this with Outlook on the
   Web for Office 365 using a corporate email account. I assume it
   works    equally well with consumer Office 365 accounts, but haven't
   tried it.
4. Even if you don't use Wunderlist, you could sign-up
   and use it to generate the URL when you need it.

And just for disclosure, I do work for Microsoft, though I'm not associated with either the Outlook or Wunderlist teams.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using `emacs`.

Comment: @DavidPostill Respectfully, I thought I did. That's why I included #4 as a way to obtain a URL to a message that can then be stored anywhere, including in a text file.

Comment: This answer is old and Wunderlist [no longer exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wunderlist)

Answer (score 0):

In the web app (Office 365) you can right-click the message and create task/to-do. Then in the task you can right-click and get the embedded link to the message. See related answer linked below for more detail:

[Link to Microsoft Outlook 365 Webmail email](https://superuser.com/a/1572112/226668)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a relatively non-technical work around for this question after a lot of trial and error. I save alot of emails in OneNote, and in older versions of One Note, you can drag and drop specific emails to be saved on the page. But this isn't possible in OneNote 365 (to my knowledge).

However, I have found that I can save a print out of the email in OneNote, and then copy and paste the hyperlink to the specific email in the outlook webmail interface. However, the trick/work-around as far as I can tell, is that the email CANNOT be still in the inbox, but must have been moved to a different folder. If it remains in the inbox when you copy-and-paste the hyperlink, when you click on it, it will just open the inbox, instead of opening the specific email you want. This works for me in both Chrome and Edge, I hope others also find it useful.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.