# Hyperlinks to mail in Outlook 2007 broken after moving mail to other folder within same mailbox

Tags: email, emacs, microsoft-outlook-2007, hyperlink, org-mode

I want to use hyperlinks to open single e-mail messages stored in MS Outlook 2007 from within my text files created by Emacs org-mode (as described here: [Can I create a link to a specific email message in Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/71786/can-i-create-a-link-to-a-specific-email-message-in-outlook)).

The problem is:
I can create links to the e-mail and they are working,
but they stop working as soon as I move the e-mail to another folder (within the same mailbox, even not to an external pst-file).
And even if I move the e-mail back in its original place the link does not start working again.

However, if I create a new link after moving the e-mail, it seems to look exactly the same like the original one, so the GUID number of the mail seems not to change after moving (as I would expect it).

Can anyone help?

- Does the GUID stay the same when moving an e-mail in Outlook 2007 (within the same mailbox file)?
- If yes, why do I get an error message like "the action could not be performed" (sorry, I don't know the exact wording at the moment) after moving the linked e-mail?
- Is there a solution (except first moving the message and then creating the hyperlink)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself:

At least in Outlook 2007 the GUID **does** change, as soon as an e-mail is moved - even only within the same mailbox file and not to another pst-file. :-(

So there seems to be no on-board way to preserve the ID - the only way would be to read out the GUID of an element before and after moving it and then replace the old GUID in the org-mode text files by the new one, but this seems quite complicated.