# Get the Guid (not the entry ID) of an Outlook Message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, guid

As mentioned in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/71786/can-i-create-a-link-to-a-specific-email-message-in-outlook), it is possible to grab the entryID from Outlook messages.

But the problem is if theses messages are moved to another folder, the ID changes.

So, I guess I need the GUID, but I don't know how I can grab this via a macro in Outlook. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Use [PR_SEARCH_KEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815908.aspx) (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102 for PropertyAccessor and Folder.GetTable filter).

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: Reference to what? You can download MFCMAPI and see all properties by yourself.

Comment: For the EntryId part, not a reference for something *not* existing.

Comment: @Raystafarian, thanks for mentioning, fixed the post. I mean, PR_SEARCH_KEY, of course. It only changes when moving between stores.